# Is there a common pattern to instantiate a library class as a singleton and have the library able to access that instance internally?

Tags: java, kotlin, design-patterns

Say I have a library project which provides a class `MyService`.

I'd like clients to be able to instantiate MyService as a singleton and at the same time, I'd like the library to be able to access that singleton internally.

Now I can do the standard `MyService.getInstance()` sort of thing, but that doesn't lead to a very testable code if my library has `MyService.getInstance()` calls all over the place.

Perhaps any classes in the library that need an instance of MyService can take in MyService as a constructor parameter:

```
class MyTestableClass(val myService: MyService) {
    // Now this class can be unit tested with a mock/fake MyService
}
```

But at some higher level in the library I'm still going to have to pass `MyService.getInstance()` to this class.

Is there a standard pattern to accomplish this? Basically I want the client to be able to instantiate MyService as a singleton and also have the library able to access that instance internally, while having the ability to swap out the singleton instance with a mock/fake for unit testing.

Comment: This depends somewhat on the nature of your "library class."  Not all "library classes" _should_ be possible to "swap out with a mock/fake."

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say there is a single standard way of achieving this. But here is a approach I used for some libraries in the past.

In Kotlin one possibility to provide the singleton for you is to make use of the `lazy` delegate. Alternatively you can use an `object` instead.

```kotlin
public interface SingletonTarget {}

internal class SingletonClassImpl: SingletonTarget {}
public val mySingleton: SingletonTarget by lazy { SingletonClassImpl () }
// or
public object SingletonObjectImpl: SingletonTarget {}
```

Both can be combined with constructor injection easily.

```kotlin
public fun interface BookFlight {
   operator fun invoke(): Unit
} 
internal class BookFlightService(private val service: SingletonTarget): BookFlight { ... }
```

You can provide instances of your functions using factories. This might also be the right place to "glue" your singleton to the library functions.

```kotlin
public fun BookFlight(): BookFlight = 
   BookFlightService(mySingleton) // or SingletonObjectImpl
```